# Redis exception raised in gen_server

Tags: erlang, redis

I am trying to insert 10000 records in redis from erlang using gen_server. However, i get following exception

```
exception exit: {connection_error,{connection_error,eaddrnotavail}}
```

Note:-

- Ports range on redis server is sufficient
- Redis is configured to accept 10000 connections at once
- I also tried using timer:sleep to rule out the possibility of connections are getting full.
- I am starting connection , firing query and closing connection immediately
- Call from gen_server to redis is synchronous
- I am using eredis as a library
- I get this error approximately 200 to 500 insertions in redis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got It worked :) Posting answer so that it can help others...

Problem was kernal TIME_WAIT.

Eredis was using gen_tcp and as I was inside the fast network and generating 10000 connections   Many of the connections was in TIME_WAIT state and eredis was using resuse addr to true so Although I close the connection in my code OS was the port which were in TIME_WAIT state and erlang was again trying to connect to that port.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the posting. 
Posting some of my changes as well.

change the eredis.hrl from

-define(SOCKET_OPTS, [binary, {active, once}, {packet, raw}, {reuseaddr, true}]).

to

-define(SOCKET_OPTS, [binary, {active, once}, {packet, raw}, {reuseaddr, false}]).